# SpringBoot read a json file using @Value annotation and convert it to map

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new to SpringBoot, and I need to load a json file and convert it to Java map.

Code:

```java
@Service
public class StatisticsService {
    
    @Value("classpath:/mocks/Docs.json")
    private Resource resourceFile;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    // rest of the code ...

    private void convertData() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(resourceFile.getInputStream(), typeRef);
        
        System.out.println(map);
    }    
}
```

I tried to change the classpath value of @Value annotation, but didn't work for me!

## UPDATE

I figured that the resourceFile is null when reaching the Service constructor, but if I reach the service later (by acquiring an entry point for example localhost:8080/statistics), then it's populated.

Answer (score 0):

As `DocsConditionNew.json` resides in your classpath, just use:

```
@Value("classpath:DocsConditionNew.json")
private Resource resourceFile;
```

`@Value` supports other prefixes, too, like:

`file:` for referencing a file out of your classpath, but on your computer, and
`URL:` for remote files.

Comment: Hi, I tried that already... but getting resourceFile as null !

Comment: Getting null as well when using the full path of the file: @Value("file: C:\\Users\\<user>\\Documents\\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.9.0.RELEASE\\...\\DocsConditionNew.json")

Comment: Your class should be a Spring component. Make sure to add @Service above your class.

Comment: Yes I have it, but it was deleted when I accepted an edit. However, I came over another approch: https://github.com/danvega/spring-boot-jsontodb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/therealdanvega/JsontodbApplication.java which reads the json inside the Application as a @Bean, and it seems working from there (got other exception to mapping to my java objects, but that is another issue)

Comment: Actually I checked myself again, and it's not related... the resourceFile is null when entering the Service constructor, but If I reach after that (by calling localhost:8080/statistic) then it's populated.